# How to implement retries on spring kafka producer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'd like to set up 3 retries. Here's what I'm visualizing, if the producer is done retrying 3 times and still hasn't sent the message, it should go to a local topic (dlt).

Here's what I'm working with right now. This is the configuration

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configure,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configure.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template), new FixedBackOff(0L, 2)));
        return factory;
    }
```

This is the main application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafka
@Retryable(value = Exception.class, maxAttemptsExpression = "3",
        backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "1000"))
public class KafkaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(KafkaApplication.class, args);
        TestBean testBean = context.getBean(TestBean.class);
        while(true){
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(5000);

                } catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("exception" + e.getMessage());
                }
                testBean.send("This is message " + i);
            }
            context.getBean(Consumer.Listener.class).latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

    }
```

This is the listener

```
@KafkaListener(topics = AppConfiguration.topic, groupId = AppConfiguration.groupid, containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
        public void listen(@Payload String message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
            try{
                System.out.println("Successfully Received: " + message + " (partition: " + partition + ")");
                this.latch.countDown();
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error in sending record");
                System.out.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I think you need to look at the `RetryTopicConfigurer` https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic/RetryTopicConfigurer.html for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to retry 3 times and don't want too many components to be redundant, you can choose to use try catch to cooperate with the local Queue implementation.

The simplest is to **try again immediately after an error occurs**. Of course, many times you will want to **retry again every few minutes**. At this time, you only need to put the error message into a queue in the catch, and then **take out the queue data from another method and send it again**.
But maybe kafka has solved this problem for you, **some exceptions can be retried automatically**, I suggest you to understand: https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation.html#producerconfigs

The following is the simplest implementation：

```
public void sendToKafka(String topic, String key, String value, Integer retryTimes) {
        try {
            kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //if retryTimes
            if (retryTimes < 3) {
                sendToKafka(topic, key, value, ++retryTimes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate how to do that? Do you have a github repo with that implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't made a concrete realization. I wrote a simple example and more detailed instructions in my answer, and attached official documents that might help you.

Comment: Yes, they are implemented on the spring framework. If you need to learn how to use kafka and its configuration more conveniently on spring, this can help you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.10/reference/html/#with-java-configuration-no-spring-boot

Comment: Resiliency4j is a great framework for retries and other resiliency patterns as well.

You can configure to retry when your producer throws a KafkaException.

Sound like you need to configure a circuit breaker as well, so you can send your message to dlt when the retries are exhausted.

Docs are at https://resilience4j.readme.io

Answer (score 1):

Kafka  directly supports this configuration in its producers as mentioned [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_retries).

The best way to do so though is using a combination of *delivery.timeout.ms*, *request.timeout.ms* and *retry.backoff.ms* properties to control how many retries will happen within a given period of time, as explained in the docs.

If you are using Spring Boot, you can configure a bean as follows:

```java
  @Bean(name = "ProducerConfig")
  public Map<String, Object> producerConfig() {
    return Map.of(
        ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
        bootstrapServers,
        // Enable safely ordered retries
        ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true",
        ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all",
        // Config number of retries
        ProducerConfig.DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 5000,
        ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 200, 
        ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 500
    );

  }
```